# custom border for ImageView

Tags: android, xml, layer-list

I want to remove the peach solid color from interior portion and just want it at the border of top, left and right. The bottom color red is fine. I searched everywhere but they only suggested to use solid to overlap the whole red border.

XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- Draw a 2dp width border around shape -->
            <stroke
                android:color="#ff1e0c"
                android:width="2dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Overlap the left, top and right border using background color  -->
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fffbce"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image: present look]

Comment: can you illustrate how actually need this?

Comment: I want to make layer like that http://imgur.com/DQt8arf

Comment: if you are using tab-host then you can add divider easly it will affect as well you need

Comment: Not using tabhost. Just ImageView in LinearLayout @Survivor.

Answer (score 1):

try this solution,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is the line -->
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="-1dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

Comment: The code changes the whole border color to red @Amit.

Comment: here you will get red at botton and black on three other sides , thats what you wanted right ? @sam

Comment: Yes, I'm getting it but It does not looks good as bottom still has some black color. Also, if I increase dp of red color, it doesnot increases, it just jumps to a level higher than the bottom black border. @Amit

Comment: I think the better option would be to use something like View and change the color of it when ImageView are clicked.

Comment: red color on increasing dp will not change as it is overtiring on black color. so i think this is best solution for border you wanted with xml. @sam

Comment: As this was not not much of a help so I can't accept the answer but yes its the most close I can get via xml so +1 for you. @Amit